# Datastax java driver, convert scala collections to java error

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to store a Scala Map (that I'm trying to convert to a java.util.Map) into cassandra 2.1.8.

The data structure looks like this:

```
Map[String -> Set[Tuple[String, String, String]]]
```

I created the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE mailing (emailaddr text PRIMARY KEY, totalmails bigint, emails map<text, frozen<set<tuple<text, text, text>>>>);
```

I first try to convert the Set's to java Set's:

```
def emailsToCassandra(addr: emailAddress, mail: MailContent, number: Int) = {
println("Inserting emails into cassandra")

mail.emails.foreach(result =>

  setAsJavaSet(result._2)
)
```

I then build the query and attempt to convert the Map to a java Map:

```
val query = QueryBuilder.insertInto("emails", "mailing")
                        .value("emailAddr", addr.toString())
                        .value("totalmails", number)
                        .value("emails", mapAsJavaMap(mail.emails))
session.executeAsync(query)
```

I get back:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value 1 of type class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper does not correspond to any CQL3 type
```

I also tried to do this:

```
val lol = mail.emails.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, java.util.Set[Tuple3[String, String, String]]]]
```

Which didn't work

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things you are going to need to overcome here:

1. Converting the map into the java.util.Map type. (You've already covered this by using mapAsJavaMap)
2. Converting the Set[Tuple3] into a java.util.Set type.
3. Converting Tuple3 into a [TupleValue](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/tupleTypes.html).

Unfortunately the error returned by the driver (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value 1 of type class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper does not correspond to any CQL3 type`) is misleading, as the Map type is converting correctly in your code, but the Tuple3 type is ultimately what it is having problems with.  I opened up [JAVA-833](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-833) to track this.

I'm making assumptions about what MailContent is, but here is some code that should make things work.  The main logic that does the heavy lifting is `emailsToCql` which maps `Tuple3[String, String, String]` into `TupleValue`, Set to java.util.Set and Map to java.util.Map.

```scala
import com.datastax.driver.core.{DataType, TupleType, Cluster}
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object Scratch extends App {

  val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build()
  val session = cluster.connect()

  session.execute("create keyspace if not exists emails WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };")
  session.execute("create table if not exists emails.mailing (emailaddr text PRIMARY KEY, totalmails bigint, emails map<text, frozen<set<tuple<text, text, text>>>>);")

  val emailType = TupleType.of(DataType.text(), DataType.text(), DataType.text())

  case class MailContent(addr: String, emails: Map[String, Set[Tuple3[String, String, String]]]) {
    lazy val emailsToCql = emails.mapValues {
      _.map(v => emailType.newValue(v._1, v._2, v._3)).asJava
    }.asJava
  }

  val mailContent = MailContent("test@email.com", Map(
    "dest@email.com" -> Set(("field1", "field2", "field3")),
    "dest2@email.com" -> Set(("2field1", "2field2", "2field3"))))

  val query = QueryBuilder.insertInto("emails", "mailing")
                .value("emailAddr", mailContent.addr)
                .value("totalmails", mailContent.emails.size)
                .value("emails", mailContent.emailsToCql)

  session.execute(query)

  cluster.close()
}
```

This yields a record that looks like the following in cqlsh:

```
 emailaddr      | emails                                                                                                       | totalmails
----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 test@email.com | {'dest2@email.com': {('2field1', '2field2', '2field3')}, 'dest@email.com': {('field1', 'field2', 'field3')}} |          2
```

Answer (score 3):

I am far from being a Scala expert, but the error looks like Scala "convertion" to Java Map means to encapsulate it into a *scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper* that extends *java.util.AbstractMap* which, in turn, implements *java.util.Map*. When Cassandra tries to map from Java's types to its own it doesn't encounter MapWrapper as a valid type.

I would recommend you to write your own method to convert the whole thing (MailContent, right?) from a Map[String -> Set[Tuple[String, String, String]]] to a similar structure using Java's equivalents: HashMap and HashSet (shrug). Also, you should have problems with the TupleType so you should use Cassandra's TupleType during this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

user2244255 was right, separating it out into it's own method helped me understand what was going on. Here is the final code that worked:

```
def resultToJavaMap(mail: MailContent) ={

 mapAsJavaMap(mail.emails.mapValues{result =>

  setAsJavaSet(result.map {lol =>
    val theType = TupleType.of(DataType.text(), DataType.text(), DataType.text())
    val theValue = theType.newValue()
    theValue.setString(0, lol.to.toString())
    theValue.setString(1, lol.subject)
    theValue.setString(2, lol.message)
  })

})
```

Essentially you access the tuples in the Set, change them to the datastax type, then change the entire set to a java.util.Set then change the entire thing to a java.util.Map